# Google maps clear all markers before placing new one

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to place a marker on click in google maps along with populating input boxes with the lat and lng. I need the code to clear all the existing markers first before placing the new marker and updating the lat and lng. everything works except when I add code to try clear all the markers.

The below code works perfectly but does not clear the old markers before placing the new one.

Thank you.

Working code without clearing existing markers...

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

var map;


  function initMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29, 25);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: latlng,
    });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
            var marker_position = event.latLng;   
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: false
        }); 
   marker.setPosition(marker_position);   
   document.getElementById("latFld").value = event.latLng.lat();
   document.getElementById("lngFld").value = event.latLng.lng();
})                      
  }  
    </script>
```

Not working code with clearing markers before adding a new one...

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

var map;
    var markersArray = [];

  function initMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29, 25);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
    });
            markersArray.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(event){});
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
            var marker_position = event.latLng;   
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: false
        });
   clearOverlays();
   marker.setPosition(marker_position);   
   document.getElementById("latFld").value = event.latLng.lat();
   document.getElementById("lngFld").value = event.latLng.lng();
})   

  }

  function clearOverlays() {
for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: it seems that it could be sufficient just to place `if(marker) marker.setMap(null)` before the `marker = new google.maps.Marker({` line in the first version of your code, i.e., to delete the marker if it already exists and then proceed with creation of the new one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seem you have placed the code in the wrong place  .. try

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

var map;
var markersArray = [];

function initMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29, 25);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
    });

   clearOverlays();
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: false
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(event){});
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
    var marker_position = event.latLng;   
        marker.setPosition(marker_position);   
        markersArray.push(marker);
       document.getElementById("latFld").value = event.latLng.lat();
       document.getElementById("lngFld").value = event.latLng.lng();
    })   
} 

function clearOverlays() {
for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray = [];
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciated.

Comment: it helped me too.